# Why is this returning false?

Tags: c#, boolean, logic

So I have this check method that returns true if all the parameters are met, and returns false if not. My question is this... Why does (c <= 'a' && c >= 'z' || c == '/') equate to false when an input of:

*fiddler 01010100 10011100 /ro* ?

*Line is marked

```
public static bool check(string action)
{
    string[] arguments = action.Split(' ');
    if (arguments.Length > 3)
    {
        string[] time = { arguments[1], arguments[2] };
        for (int i = 1; i < time.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1 || i == 2)
                foreach (char c in time[i])
                {
                    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') { }
                    else return false;
                }
            else break;
        }
        for (int i = arguments.Length - 1; i >= 3; i--)
        {
            if (i != 1 || i != 2 && arguments[i] != "")
            {
                foreach (char c in arguments[i])
                {
     >>> >>> >>>    if (c <= 'a' && c >= 'z' || c == '/') { }
                    else return false;
                }
                if (arguments[i] == " " || arguments[i] == null || call.arguments.Contains(arguments[i]) == true) { }
                else return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (arguments.Length == 3)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= arguments.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1 || i == 2)
            {
                foreach (char c in arguments[i])
                {
                    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') { }
                    else return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (char c in arguments[i].ToUpper())
                {
                    if (c <= 'a' && c >= 'z' || c == '/') { }
                    else return false;
                }
                if (arguments[i] == " " || arguments[i] == null || call.arguments.Contains(arguments[i]) == true) { }
                else return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: your post and your code don't match - you have 2 opposite expressions - make sure you have the right one `(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' || c == '/')` or `(c <= 'a' && c >= 'z' || c == '/')`

Comment: Can you prepare a minimal valuable example of your problem? I don't think the entire method is important here, as you're asking about specific part of your code.

Comment: `c <= 'a' && c >= 'z'` this will never be true. Unless am missing something this is as same as comparing `c <=1 && c >= 26` which doesn't makes sense

Comment: You _are_ aware that arrays in C# are zero-based, not 1-based?

Comment: There are too many things wrong with this code, I suggest you focus on one problem and ask a single question per problem.

Comment: so we can assume that you expect `"fiddler 01010100 10011100 /ro"` to be true. But why?

Comment: @ John: Yes I'm aware of that; @ Sriram: A good nights sleep cures a lot of things, even apparent dyslexia. My bad XD; @ RadioSpace: I assumed it was true because after checking for a valid time (two sets of MMDDHHMM) I again check for more arguments, - 1 because I am not counting index 0 as this method is for checking index's 1 & 2 & 3+, but my error i checking was the error of using equality comparison incorrectly. So in sum my assumption was incorrect until now.; Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the expression is `c <= 'a' && c >= 'z'` They can't be both true, so it is always false. You probably mean to write `c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'`

Comment: Sorry for the late response and accepting of the correct answer. Life issues prevail after all. Thank you for correcting my errors!

Answer (score 1):

Your code has so many errors.

Firstly, in this part of code:

```
string[] time = { arguments[1], arguments[2] };
for (int i = 1; i < time.Length; i++)
{
     if (i == 1 || i == 2)
```

`i` never be equal to `2`, because (`2 >= time.Length`). You should use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < time.Length; i++)
```

without any checking.

Secondly, this part:

```
for (int i = arguments.Length - 1; i >= 3; i--)
{
    if (i != 1 || i != 2 && arguments[i] != "")
```

`i` never be equal to `1` or `2`, beacause this checking already been in `for` statement. You should remove this checking for clearing your code.

Thirdly, this check `c <= 'a' && c >= 'z'` is always false, because `'z' > 'a'`. You probably should use this `c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'`.

Good luck and will be more careful!

Comment: Thank you for the corrections of my stupid mistakes... I can't believe I actually wrote that.